# CodeIgniter querybuilder convert query no results

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I'm trying to convert a query to CodeIgniter's query builder.

Original version:

```
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT tb.*,b.`property` FROM `email_template_blocks` as tb inner join email_blocks as b on tb.`block_id`=b.`id` where tb.template_id=' . $id);
    if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    return $query->result_array();
```

Query builder version:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('email_template_blocks');
$this->db->join('email_blocks', 'email_template_blocks.block_id = email_blocks.id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('email_template_blocks.template_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
//$query = $this->db->query('SELECT tb.*,b.`property` FROM `email_template_blocks` as tb inner join email_blocks as b on tb.`block_id`=b.`id` where tb.template_id=' . $id);
if ($query->num_rows() < 1) {
    return null;
}
return $query->result_array();
```

The query builder version returns no results (no error messages either and I have db debug on). I'm fairly certain I'm doing something wrong, but I find the CI documentation on joins lacking. How can I fix this?

I'd also like to know how to select all of the items from the `email_template_blocks` table and just join the `property` column of the `email_blocks` table.

Email template blocks table:

[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTZkL.png)

Email blocks table:

[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODnh1.png)

Comment: As a side note, do you escape `$id` in your non-qb version?

Comment: remove single quote from columns and table name from your original version